# Gaussian quadrature rule for $x^{1/3}$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, singular-integrals

I'm trying to understand the generalized Gaussian quadrature rules for singularities at one of the endpoints. For this I studied this [paper](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~daan.huybrechs/research/TW523.pdf) by Daan Huybrechs.
On page 12 there are the plots for the functions $R_n$ and $S_n$ for $n = 0, ..., 4$. I tried to calculate the functions $R_n$ and $S_n$ for $\psi(x) = x^{1/3}$, also with the way explained in chapter 4.3, but I don't know how to calculate the quadrature points.

What is the correct way to calculate those points $x_j$?